# Lucky numbers in MySQL - delete every nth row

Tags: mysql, counting

I'm trying to recreate the lucky numbers up to a very large number in MySQL for a recreational maths problem.

The rule is essentially 'look at the nth number in a list of numbers and then remove every nth instance after it.

The simplest example is the second number in the list of natural numbers '2'.  So we would remove 2 then 4 then 6 then 8 etc.  You would then look at the next number '3' and remove the 3rd, 6th, 9th terms.  The interesting part comes from the fact that you completely remove these numbers from the list of numbers so it is very different from normal maths.  The next number after '3' is '7' because you've removed 4, 5 and 6 already so you then look at deleting every seventh entry.

This essentially is just counting and not actually maths - which I can do really well in PHP and MySQL together.  the problem I face is that you have to get the whole array from the database in one go and as you reach hundreds of millions an ordinary computer just cannot cope memory-wise.  This problem needs to be done solely in SQL with no transferring of data between programmes.

For more info on Lucky Numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_number explained much better than I have above.

I have a database of odd integers up to 1,000,000,000 (8 GB) (i.e. already removed every 2nd term).  I can quite happily get the next number to use (call it x) in PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID LIMIT n,1
```

with a do-while loop to count from n = 3-1,000,000,000 (in reality the top limit of n might become around 150,000,000 as lots of numbers are deleted) but each time (during the loop) it will then need to ask the database to delete each xth number.

This is the code I have to select each xth number from another stackoverflow question:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, [column name] 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, [table name] 
    ) ranked 
WHERE rownum % [x] = 1
```

I think I just need this to become a delete statement but I'm really struggling with that.  I'm a PHP programmer with only moderate SQL knowledge.  By doing this I would only be transferring **instructions** between MySQL and PHP and not lots of data.

However if anyone wants to go the whole hog and write the loop in MySQL (not just the delete statement and I don't know if it is even possible!) then I would make great use of it.

Comment: Fetch all the ids which would be deleted, then just run them through `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id IN ($ids)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `id`'s from this query to delete, using an [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) condition

```
SELECT * FROM [table name]
-- change this to DELETE FROM [table name] when you're confident
WHERE `id` IN (
    SELECT `id`
    -- * became `id` so that we can use it in IN() above
    FROM (
        SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS 'rownum', t.`id`
        FROM (SELECT @row :=0) r, (SELECT `id` FROM [table name] ORDER BY `id`) t
        -- I made it order first because it showed an
        -- unexpected ordering for a table I tried this on
    ) ranked
    WHERE `rownum` % [n] = 0
    -- and I changed 1 into 0 because that's what we actually need
)
```

Make sure the select statement selects exactly what you need before deleting. To check if you have selected the right records you can try the following. Change 3 into some other number that you want to use. Also, don't forget to change `[table name]` into the name of your table.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS 'rownum', t.`id`
    FROM (SELECT @row :=0) r, (SELECT `id` FROM [table name] ORDER BY `id`) t
) ranked
WHERE `rownum` % 3 = 0
```

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to answer, when I copy this in and do it on a test file I get no rows returned for %3=1 but every row for %3=0 so i'm not quite sure what is going on there.  when adding the delete statement in (for a test table) I get an error on the select statement.

Comment: Please use -- for comments in SQL, not #. :)

Comment: @RenéWolferink I didn't know it rendered the comments with `--` right. Just corrected those.

Comment: My code:
SELECT * FROM lucky
-- change this to DELETE FROM [table name] when you're confident
WHERE lucky.integer IN (
    SELECT lucky.integer
    -- * became `id` so that we can use it in IN() above
    FROM (
        SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS 'rownum', t.integer
        FROM (SELECT @row :=0) r, (SELECT lucky.integer FROM lucky ORDER BY lucky.integer) t
        -- I made it order first because it showed an
        -- unexpected ordering for a table I tried this on
    ) ranked
    WHERE 'rownum' % 7 = 0
   
)
Can't get it nicely formatted!

Comment: @user1967034 it does not really bring every row to me - at least with 3 different tables I tried. Are you sure about that? Perhaps you might have some other issue with your id's..?

Comment: I still get every row out though and not every 7th.  Could it be my version of MySQL 5.0.4?

Comment: hmm that is strange, i'll look into it, but I do really appreciate your help

Comment: @user1967034 Try `SELECT integer` instead of `SELECT lucky.integer`. It should be addressing the `integer` value from subquery instead of that from the main table/query. I coudn't escape it here in the comment but don't forget to escape **integer** here because it's a keyword.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM lucky
WHERE integera IN (
    SELECT integera
    FROM (
        SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS 'rownum', t.integera
        FROM (SELECT @row :=0) r, (SELECT integera FROM lucky ORDER BY integera) t
    ) ranked
    WHERE 'rownum' % 7 = 0
)`
Changed integer to integera in the schema to ensure it wasn't getting mixed up and then altered code but still get every row

Comment: @user1967034 You might want to try it with the 2nd code I wrote above. Also, consider that `id` is a unique, auto-incrementing column. So in your case there might need some tweak. I can't take this to chat since it requires that each party has min 20 pts. Sorry about that.

Comment: the second code works perfectly for select, I guess I can't make it delete very easily though as that is how you derived the first code. integera is the only column in my table now and is autoincrement.
I feel like I'm so close to cracking this.

Comment: i got it, I kept changing the apostrophes on the where statement which is what i thought i should be doing.  i forgot to do it that last time and it worked perfectly.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @user1967034 I missed that, too. Good catch, and glad to help.